# Laratrust attachRole returns 404 error on staging

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/) package for my roles management. Everything worked fine on my local developement. However, I've tried to upload my project to my server. Now, if I want to attach or detach a role, my application just redirects to a `404` error page.

What is going on?

This occures on registration, this is my registration logic:

**myController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->attachRole('user');
    $verifyUser = \App\VerifyEmail::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user, $verifyUser));

    return $user;
}
```

If i remove the `$user->attachRole`, everything works fine.

I am not getting any errors, just the `404` page. How can I fix this?

I've created a new application key, I have run all my migrations and installed all composer packages.

Comment: Is your server setup for URL rewrites? Sounds like it could be something to do with that.

Comment: I think so, every url works. I have multiple laravel projects running on this server, all using laratrust. No proplems there. And what I dont understand is that laratrust shouldn't redirect to any route. the route i am getting the 404 error is `/registration`, so no redicect

Comment: Check the `laravel.log` file and paste the trace error.

Comment: @HCK its not getting logged

Comment: @PatrickSchocke try to add a `dd("Yeah, I'm here!");` in the first line of your method, to know if your call is reaching the method.

Comment: I've done it. It is getting renderd. But if I place it after the ` $user->attachRole('user');`, it isn't. So the method breaks at this

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if the record is created?

Comment: Oh boy, thanks for this. It was - as allways - my fault. I've migrated all files, but I didn't run the seeder. so there were no roles. It is stupid, that laratrust returns than a 404 page, but however... it is working now. Thanks!